# When can we say $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ given their presentations?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Consider $F_2=\langle a,b \rangle$, the free group on $2$ letters.

If I look at $H=\langle ab,ba^{-1}, bab^{-1} \rangle$ (the generators are arbitrary), since each generator can be made from $a$ and $b$, $H \subseteq F_2$ and by definition of the presentation, it's a group so $H \le F_2$  ($H$ is a subgroup of $F_2$).

When exactly can I not use this logic? Specifically, is it true if I simply have that "the generating set of $H$ can be made by the generators of $G$", that $H \le G$?

I don't think it is true, because we could look at $H = \langle a, a^4=1\rangle$, and even though the generating set of $H$ sits inside that of $F_2$, $H$ is a finite group and not a subgroup of $F_2$ (finite groups are non-free and subgroups of free groups are free).

Then I thought perhaps the generators and the relators in $H$ must be derivable from those in $G$, which in the case of $F_2$ would mean that any subgroup should have generators made by $a,b$, and no nontrivial relators (i.e. the relators in the subgroup must be the trivial relation in the group)  , but that is kind of assuming that the subgroups of free groups are free.

So in essence, given $H= \langle S_H \ | \  R_H \rangle$ and $G= \langle S_G \ | \  R_G \rangle$, when can we say $H \le G$?

Comment: Generally speaking, one usually takes presentations "one at a time." If I am given $G= \langle x,y\mid xy=yx\rangle$, and $H=\langle x,y\mid xy=yx, x^2=1\rangle$ separately, then I tend to think that these are descriptions of *two* groups and that no assertion is being made about one being a subgroup or quotient of another, even though they are both described in terms of generators with the same "names", *unless explicitly told* that one is meant to be a subgroup of the other. Of course, it is possible that one may find embeddings (or surjections) of one into the other.

Comment: We need to be careful here: presentations are not groups; rather, they *define* groups. So instead you mean: "Given $H\equiv\langle S_H \ | \  R_H \rangle$ and $G\equiv \langle S_G \ | \  R_G \rangle$, when can we say $H \cong K$ for $K\le G$?" (Here $\equiv$ means "is the group defined by the presentation".)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Okay. So I was thinking of this: If I'm given $H \cong \langle b,b^3| \rangle$, can I say that  $H$ is isomorphic to a free group because it is a subgroup of $\langle a,b \rangle$? If no, why? If yes, what am I assuming to say that $H$ is a subgroup of $\langle a,b \rangle$?

Comment: First, you wouldn't write $H$ that way. That's not a presentation because your generators are not distinct variables. Second, no, you cannot justify it that way. You can say that $\langle b\mid\rangle$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\langle a,b\mid\rangle$ by invoking von Dyck's theorem, not just because the presentations happen to use the same letters.